# Pointer errors unclear in BST

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have been trying for the better part of today to find where my bug is in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

void fileConnect(BST &Book)
{
    std::fstream inFile;
    inFile.open("inFile.txt", std::ios::in);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening input file!\n";
        exit(101);
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nInput file found.\n\n";

        do
        {
            Node* tempHold;
            tempHold = new Node;

            std::getline(inFile, tempHold->first, '$');
            std::getline(inFile, tempHold->last, '$');
            std::getline(inFile, tempHold->phone);

            tempHold->key = toupper(tempHold->last[0]);

            Book.insertBST(tempHold);

        } while (!inFile.eof());

    }

    inFile.close();
}

void menuDisplay(BST *Book)
{
    int selection = 0;
    bool valid = true, wiped = false;

    std::cout << "This Phonebook will allow you to add or delete entries, search for a specific\nentry, list all entries, or delete all entries." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << "To begin, please select an option from the menu below: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1) Search by last name." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2) Delete an entry from the phonebook." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3) Add an entry to the phonebook." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4) Print all entries in the phonebook." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5) Delete all entries in the phonebook." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6) Exit Program." << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nChoose an option: ";
        std::cin >> selection;

        if (selection < 1 || selection >= 7)
        {
            std::cout << "\nERROR: Please enter a valid choice between 1 and 7." << std::endl;
            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = true;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            //Search
            if(selection == 1)
            {
                std::string term;
                cout << "Please enter the last name of the person you want to search for:" << endl;
                cin >> term;
                Book->pubSearch(term);
            }

            //Delete individual
            if(selection == 2)
            {
                std::string dltString;
                cout << "Please enter the last name of the individual you would like to delete:" << endl;
                cin >> dltString;

                int dltKey = dltString[0];

                Book->deleteNode(dltKey);
            }

            //Add individual
            if(selection == 3)
            {
                Node* tempHold;
                tempHold = new Node;
                std::string first, last, phone;

                cout << "First name: ";
                first.clear();
                cin >> first;
                cout << "Last name: ";
                last.clear();
                cin >> last;
                cout << "Phone number: ";
                phone.clear();
                cin >> phone;

                tempHold->key = toupper(tempHold->last[0]);

                Book->insertBST(tempHold);

                wiped = false;
            }

            //Print all
            if(selection == 4)
            {
                if(wiped)
                {
                    cout << "The phonebook was previously cleared, please add more entries or exit." << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    Book->printTree();
                }
            }

            //Delete all
            if(selection == 5)
            {
                std::string confirm;
                std::cout << "Are you sure you want to delete all entries? Y/N" << endl;
                cin >> confirm;

                if(confirm[0] == 'Y' || confirm[0] == 'y')
                {
                    cout << "Deleting data..." << endl;
                    Book->pubDestroy();
                    wiped = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Operation canceled." << endl;
                }
            }
            //Exit
            if(selection == 6)
            {
                std::cout << "Program will now exit, goodbye!" << std::endl;
                exit(100);
            }
        }
    } while (valid);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    ///<Local Declarations and initializations of BST
    BST Book;
    int dltKey = 0, newKey = 0;

    fileConnect(Book);

    menuDisplay(&Book);

    return 0;
}
```

[This is a live demo](http://goo.gl/8q6eDy) so it's easier to see what I mean from the output.

I know that it's a pointer error, but I can't quite figure out where. When I run this in VS2013 it just hangs and crashes before anything can be done in the program. When run in Linux, it will run but any modification of my data will trash the rest of it. I also can't add any new nodes to the tree after the initial file read-in.

If I had to guess it has to do with the way I'm passing my class through to my functions, but I'm not familiar enough with the way classes/objects are handled automatically as function parameters.

I've tried to re-write this from the ground up at least 3 times and every time it comes back to odd pointer errors. It's maddening and I just want to see this thing work.

Thanks for all help in advance.

EDIT: Also, I don't know if it will help at all to clarify that I have issues where my data is trashed upon a non-root deletion, and using the manual add function simply doesn't link in to the tree.

Comment: Where are you copying the first, last, phone and key for the newly created  node?

Comment: Do you mean with the manual addition? The link in the post has the data file I'm initially reading from, otherwise when selecting "Add" the user will just type the data in and it's read and copied as strings.

Comment: Hey, that is what i'm asking. where are the strings read from keyboard copied? please tell me the function or file name

Comment: The function is in the `Impl.cpp` file, named `insertBST`. When I follow that with a debugger it will follow the wrong logic despite being setup properly. Ex: `walker` is a Node* type that should register as null and cause the loop to terminate during insertion, but when it becomes null the loop continues to iterate until a false null occurs and no placement logic executes.

Answer (score 2):

I think when inserting manually from option 3 you missed out on copying the first, last and phone keyed in by the user. So please modify the `menuDisplay()` function as follows:

```
//Add individual
if(selection == 3)
    {
     Node* tempHold;
     tempHold = new Node;
     std::string first, last, phone;

     cout << "First name: ";
     first.clear();
     cin >> first;
     cout << "Last name: ";
     last.clear();
     cin >> last;
     cout << "Phone number: ";
     phone.clear();
     cin >> phone;

     //You missed out these lines:       
     tempHold->first= first;
     tempHold->last=last;
     tempHold->phone= phone;

     tempHold->key = toupper(tempHold->last[0]);

     Book->insertBST(tempHold);
     wiped = false;
     }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow, yeah I definitely 100% was missing that! Thanks for pointing that out, but it didn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: tell me the exact issue. please i am unable to infer it from question. tell me the testcase which is failing and expected+observed(erroneus behaviour)

Comment: Steps: Compile + Run program; works fine.
Attempt to print whole list; works fine.
Add a name; takes input but doesn't appear in whole list.
Delete a name other than the first name in the tree; appears to remove it but trashes the remaining data in the tree and (on Linux) appears as non-keyboard symbols.

Sorry if I'm not making much sense, I've been up at this for a long time now.